# How should a form error page be rendered with Turbolinks 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, turbolinks

Using the new Turbolinks 5 in a rails application - what is the best way to render a form with error messages. The documentation says:

> Instead of submitting forms normally, submit them with XHR. In response to an XHR submit on the server, return JavaScript that performs a Turbolinks.visit to be evaluated by the browser.

So if my form submits a remote request to update should i be just doing a js form replace or does turbolinks 5 have a better way? Example -

controller:

```
def update
  @success = @team.update_attributes( team_params )
end
```

update.js

```
<% if @success %>
   Turbolinks.visit('<%= teams_path %>', {action: 'replace'});
<% else %>
   $('form').replaceWith('<%= j(render partial: '/teams/form') %>');
<% end %>
```

Is there a more turbolinks 5 way to handle the failed update?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still tinkering around as well. The only thing I'd be doing differently is put the conditional logic in the controller instead of the view.

**somethings_controller.rb**

```
def create
  if @something.save
    redirect_to @something
  else
    render 'errors'
  end
end
```

**errors.js.erb**

```
$('form').replaceWith('<%= j(render partial: 'form') %>');
```

Why does the controller-based redirect work? Because [in the docs for Turbolinks 5 it says](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#redirecting-after-a-form-submission)...

> The Turbolinks Rails engine performs this optimization automatically
>   for non-GET XHR requests that redirect with the redirect_to helper.

...which I take to mean they're basically wrapping our redirect in a `Turbolinks.visit` for us. The nice thing is that it'll degrade gracefully for users without javascript without us having to futz with `respond_to` logic.

Comment: The curious part is that if I use the normal idea of if @something.save; redirect_to @something; else; render :new; when the form fails it returns the new.html.erb response with error messages as I would expect except it doesn't update the view to display this. This would be far nicer; it feels like I'm missing something here and having to render a JS replaceWith seems unnecessary.

Comment: I'm confused about your statement from "when the form fails..." The error messages are rendered on-screen or not? How do you know the error messages are getting through?

Comment: Using chrome network inspector i can see that when I submit a form which will fail it returns a response. The HTML in the response has the error message HTML but it seems this returned response isn't been rendered on the page.

Comment: Are you using a `.js.erb` that replaces or not?

Comment: in the example in my question i was but from my further test using simply `render :new` i wasn't

Comment: Yeah, I think Turbolinks only does the heavy lifting on `remote: true` when you redirect afterwards. If you need to render, it's going to expect you to hand it a `.js` with a `replaceWith` or some other action.

Answer (score 0):

You can see why `redirect_to` works by checking out the gem: /gems/turbolinks-5.0.0.beta2/lib/turbolinks/redirection.rb

Turbolinks doesn't handle form submissions yet so you need to handle the submission and response explicitly (via remote: true or otherwise). There's a discussion about it here with some other solutions: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/85